# How to modify the labels of the target variable in OneClassSVM in python

Tags: python, scikit-learn, sklearn-pandas

I know in OneClassSVM that label -1 is outlier and 1 is inline. Then I understand that zero is the boundary. Is there a way to make the label to be printed in 2, not 3 in total? What I want to do is, to integrate OneClassSVM label like other models. For example, I found other model labeled as "0" and "1". But the code I used to run the model didn't fit with OneClassSVM model, because it returns "-1" and "1" label.

```py
for item in y_pred:
    item.replace("-1","0")
```

What I tried was, to change "-1" to "0", but I'm sure that this is not a right solution. It is necessary to finally print out only two labels without breaking the label values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the values from -1, 1 to 0,1 for example in order to represent samples that are outliers and inliers, respectively. This only for your convenience. This will not change anything in reality.

There is nothing wrong with this conversion. However, you should be careful how to interpret the results.

To change labels:

If `y_pred` is a **list** or **numpy** array:

```
y_pred = [-1, 1, -1]

y_pred_new = [0 if i==-1 else 1 for i in y_pred]

print(y_pred_new)
[0, 1, 0]
```

Why it does not really matter?

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.svm import SVC

X = np.array([[-1, -1], [-2, -1], [1, 1], [2, 1]])
y = np.array([1, 1, 2, 2])

clf = SVC(kernel='linear')
clf.fit(X, y)
print(clf.predict(X))
# array([1  1  2  2])
```

change labels and re-fit

```
X = np.array([[-1, -1], [-2, -1], [1, 1], [2, 1]])
y = np.array([-1, -1, 1, 1])

clf = SVC(kernel='linear')
clf.fit(X, y)
print(clf.predict(X))
# array([-1 -1  1  1])
```

as you can see in both cases, the first and last 2 samples are assigned with the same labels, respectively.

Comment: I know how to simply replace the values in the outputted array with other values, but I wonder if I can intentionally change the label values that are outputted to -1 and 1 in the OneClassSVM.

Comment: I updated my answer. You can change the labels for your convenience and use them in other models.

Comment: Thankyou! I used the other models like extra tree model or decision tree model.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to use the [LabelEncoder()](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.LabelEncoder.html) module of sklearn:

This allows you to map both integer and non-integer values to values between 0 and n_classes - 1.

It also has an inverse_transform() function, that allows you to transform the new labels back to the original ones.

The code to do this would become (although I'd recommend to fit the object on the true labels):

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder

LE = LabelEncoder()
y_pred_new = LE.fit_transform(y_pred)
```

And to transform back:

```
y_pred_orig = LE.inverse_transform(y_pred_new)
```